# How do I fix/calibrate my screen colors?

Tags: settings, display, color-format

*(x-post from reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/5qy9y9/how_do_i_fixcalibrate_my_screen_colors/)*

I just switched to elementary yesterday and I absolutely love it. There's a problem, though.

When I go on Twitter in Firefox, my profile picture (https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/819743601831841794/5k22sTXF_400x400.jpg) appears purple instead of blue. The weird thing is that my cover photo, which uses the same blue (https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/477405869/1484277064) is perfectly fine. There's obviously some issue with image compression or something.

Either way, both images appeared to be the same blue in Firefox in Xubuntu and Windows, so the color issue lies with elementary.

If I tilt my laptop backward, the blues match again.

I poked around in the system settings' color panel, but I don't see anything that could help me. I even installed the GNOME Color Profile Viewer, but I don't know how to use it and I'm afraid I'll mess something up if I mess around with the settings.

How do I fix/calibrate my screen colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed a custom colour profile, my blog about eOS has a section on that, https://medium.com/@SamMorrowDrums/elementaryos-one-week-in-f512553adde4#ecab

If you are happy with the colour profile in use on Xubuntu and Windows, you should be able to look at the settings to discover what profiles they are using, probably you can then export it to USB key / shared drive, and then use it on Elementary OS too. You can't screw things up too bad though, as you can just switch to another profile!

If you want to do it yourself, you can try installing [gnome-color-manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/gnome-color-manager/) or else you can look up your monitor and see if somebody has made a colour profile for your exact monitor, and try it out. If you want near-perfect colour replication, you will probably wish to avoid eye-strain reduction and night time profiles, as they will make changes to that might be less true, but more comfortable for those use cases.

A major producer of commercial colour profiles is [Laptop Media](http://laptopmedia.com/laptopmedia-profiles-list-of-supported-laptops-and-their-screens/) you might also find ones on forums etc.

I don't have the reliability of light conditions, nor the trust in myself to get it right, so I have used a commercial one, and it has really improved things.

Hope this helps - installing a profile made a world of difference. I'm really enjoying looking at neutral white again!

Comment: Thanks, although I couldn't find any profiles for my laptop's model. If I can't get the profile from Windows or Xubuntu, I'll just buy a colorimeter.

Comment: Oh that's a shame, another option is to try and find out what actual lcd panel they used making your laptop. There is a good chance another laptop uses the same model, so that's another place to look!

Comment: I have never had any luck whatsoever at changing the color profiles in linux. in elementary I've been able to set a new profile, it flashes for a bit but always, always reverts back to the default.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. Mine has been entirely stable. When does it revert back? Immediately, randomly, on wakeup or on restart?

Comment: Immediately. I've tried to change profiles on a number of distros. elementary is the only one I've even seen any kind of affect. What it does though is I set the color profile, I notice the change but after maybe one second it reverts back.

Comment: If you import the profile and then select it, it should stay, if it doesn't maybe there is an error. Perhaps you should ask this as a separate question, as the above issue should be enough for most users, and it seems your issue is more unusual.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to calibrate the monitor, the application is called DisplayCal
https://displaycal.net/

1. You install the .deb application
2. We will create the Color Profile to later install it in the system. In the application menu you can find new applications, open the Synthectic app (It comes included with DisplayCal), a large box will open with a lot of data to modify, leave them intact and click on the pre-established tab (here you can choose the color profile, in my case chose "sRGB" managing to remove the purple tones where the color was blue), and then click on save as and choose the location you want, after installing it you will not need it anymore
3. Open the Display Cal app, normally update boxes appear, you can ignore them, go to the file tab / Install moniror profile and select the .icc file that we created, a box will appear, remember to select "install profile in all the system" and you can install a profile in the system, it will ask for your user password and that's it, go back and open your browser and you'll see the change.
4. If you want, you can un-display DisplayCal and delete the .icc file, since the change is already done