# Setting right profile for external monitor HP E243d

Tags: display, color, monitors

I have HP Elitebook g3 connected to external monitor HP 24" monitor via USB-C and I can't get colours on external monitor even close to what is on Laptop - laptop screen is fine, dragging and dropping Chrome browser window from laptop screen to external display removes all shadows of grey.
I tried following all sorts of advice on [web](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199661/how-do-you-set-system-display-color-profiles-in-xubuntu-and-lubuntu), [another](https://www.reallinuxuser.com/how-to-color-calibrate-your-monitor-in-linux/), [another](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10458/how-do-i-fix-calibrate-my-screen-colors), but to know avail.
I can now change resolution and gamma correction per monitor, but I still can't find a way where external monitor displays colours reasonably, currently it looks like no shadows/no greys.

```
colormgr get-devices-by-kind display
Object Path:   /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Chimei_Innolux_Corporation_alex_1000
Owner:         alex
Created:       June 30 2020, 09:13:18 AM
Modified:      June 30 2020, 10:19:34 AM
Type:          display
Enabled:       Yes
Embedded:      Yes
Model:         HP EliteBook x360 1030 G3
Vendor:        Hewlett Packard
Serial:        unknown
Seat:          seat0
Scope:         temp
Colourspace:   rgb
Device ID:     xrandr-Chimei Innolux Corporation
Profile 1:     icc-4cbae5a38a7c0fa9e4de8532e1bf6acb
               /home/alex/.local/share/icc/edid-4a7c449feabad383ba36acbdb55c6200.icc
Metadata:      XRANDR_name=eDP-1
Metadata:      OutputPriority=secondary
Metadata:      OwnerCmdline=/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-color 
Metadata:      OutputEdidMd5=4a7c449feabad383ba36acbdb55c6200

Object Path:   /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_HP_Inc__HP_E243d_CNC90330QF_alex_1000
Owner:         alex
Created:       June 30 2020, 11:37:49 AM
Modified:      June 30 2020, 11:37:49 AM
Type:          display
Enabled:       Yes
Embedded:      No
Model:         HP E243d
Vendor:        Hewlett Packard
Serial:        CNC90330QF
Seat:          seat0
Scope:         temp
Colourspace:   rgb
Device ID:     xrandr-HP Inc.-HP E243d-CNC90330QF
Profile 1:     icc-5a42c8f4d8898737affa4fa253629350
               /home/alex/.local/share/icc/HP.icc
Profile 2:     icc-f11d711589cb96e44261fb95baa0c088
               /home/alex/.local/share/icc/edid-75ad81bba70229fde551433ac6ce2b21.icc
Profile 3:     icc-e6b0b05b63a857001a353db9ac540145
               /home/alex/.local/share/icc/edid-1cc561693c489fb94edc90bc7049dfd0.icc
Metadata:      XRANDR_name=DP-1
Metadata:      OutputPriority=primary
Metadata:      OwnerCmdline=/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-color 
Metadata:      OutputEdidMd5=1cc561693c489fb94edc90bc7049dfd0
```